# Changing existing commands/ macros frome 1 to 0 parameters

Tags: macros

How do you change an already existing command such that it works with 0 parameters?

For instance, the `\underline{}` and `\textbf{}` macros takes 1 parameter each. However, I want them to take 0 parameters so I can use them in an environment:

```
\newenvironment{e}{\textbf\underline}{}
```

or like this: `{\textbf Hello this text is BOLD.} And this is not.`
I was thinking about defining a new macro:

```
\newcommand{\underlinee}{}
```

Then my question is: How can I define this new macro? What should I write in the blanck `{}`?

Comment: for `\textbf` it is easy, just use `\bfseries` instead, but for `\underline` what do you wannt it to do? you could use the enviornm package and `\underline{\BODY}` but it does not allow line breaking so is not usually what you want for an environment.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For the underline part, I want it to underline all text inside the environment.

Comment: look at ulem package (note that thinking of turning a macro with arguments to one without is the wrong way to think of it and is not generally possible.  `\textbf` is defined by essentially `\newcommand\textbf[1]{{\bfseries #1}}` and it is `\bfseries` that you want. You can't in general define  a command with a syntax like `\bfseries` from the argument form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `soul` or `ulem`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{soul}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{obnoxious}{b}
 {\textbf{\ul{#1}}}
 {}

\begin{document}

Some text before
\begin{obnoxious}
some text in bold face and underlined. You can't use multiple paragraphs
\end{obnoxious}
and other text follows.

\end{document}
```

Of course, instead of `\textbf` it's better to use `\bfseries`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{soul}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{obnoxious}{b}
 {\bfseries\ul{#1}}
 {}

\begin{document}

Some text before
\begin{obnoxious}
some text in bold face and underlined. You can't use multiple paragraphs
\end{obnoxious}
and other text follows.

\end{document}
```

because `\textbf{text}` is mostly like `{\bfseries text}` (just a simplification).

Can you use multiple paragraphs? Yes, with some more work.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{soul}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__vebjorn_obnoxious_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__vebjorn_obnoxious_out_seq

\NewDocumentEnvironment{obnoxious}{+b}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__vebjorn_obnoxious_in_seq { \par } { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l__vebjorn_obnoxious_out_seq \l__vebjorn_obnoxious_in_seq
   {
    \exp_not:n { \ul { ##1 } }
   }
  \bfseries\seq_use:Nn \l__vebjorn_obnoxious_out_seq { \par }
 }
 {}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Some text before
\begin{obnoxious}
some text in bold face and underlined. 

You can even use multiple paragraphs
\end{obnoxious}
and other text follows.

\end{document}
```

Of course this is just for academic interest, isn't it? Long text in boldface type *and* underlined is like a punch in the eye. Underlining itself is not considered a good device in fine typography.

For this reason, I won't show an image of the result.

Comment: *For this reason, I won't show an image of the result.* Oh, I came here just to see the output!!! :)

Comment: It is actually for creating some small "headlines" in a text. Thank you.

Comment: @Vebjorn Don't underline. Never.